# Изменение размера блока от дочерних элементов

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Приветствую, на странице имеется таблица (bootstrap), находящаяся в блоке с задним фоном (скриншот). 
При увеличении кол-ва строк таблицы блок с задним фоном не увеличивается в высоту, и выходит такая штука как на скрине. От нее хочется избавиться...
Как можно эту проблему решить? Или такое изменение блока работает только с текстовым контентом внутри?

```css
table {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  width: 1400px !important;
  top: 20px;
}

.table_style {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 200px;
  min-height: 750px;
  width: 1500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table_style">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <!-- Верхушка таблицы -->
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <!-- Элементы таблицы -->
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Скрин:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: здесь указана фиксированная высота блока `height: 750px;` поэтому и не увеличивается. можно заменить на `min-height: 750px;`

Comment: К сожалению, это тоже пробовал и не получалось...
Блок будто игнорирует саму таблицу, с обычным текстом все изменяется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде как дело в том что у вас таблица, та что внутри контейнера (именно table) имеет абсолютное позиционирование, то есть по идее она никак не должна влиять на контейнер в котором находится, если я не ошибаюсь. Она не может его как-то растягивать при таком позиционировании. Попробуйте убрать `position: absolute` из стиля таблицы.

Comment: Спасибо большое!